# Convert a pandas groupby object to list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe, and want to group-by the ys:

```
   xs  ys
0   0   0
1   1   0
2   2   1
3   3   1
```

I can do this by running

```
grouped = df.groupby('ys')
```

I can iterate through this new groupby object fine, but instead I want a list of the dataframes that are accessed by `group` in the following loop:

```
for name, group in grouped:
    do_something(group)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You want a list that is accessed by a *group name*? That's impossible. You probably want a `dict`.

Comment: No, I just want a list of the dataframes and don't care about the names. Just realised my loop was wrong, should be corrected now

Answer (score 28):

Sure, just iterate over the groups!

```
>>> import pandas as pd, numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(xs=list(range(4)), ys=[0,0,1,1]))
>>> df
   xs  ys
0   0   0
1   1   0
2   2   1
3   3   1
>>> grouped = df.groupby('ys')
>>> dataframes = [group for _, group in grouped]
>>> dataframes
[   xs  ys
0   0   0
1   1   0,    xs  ys
2   2   1
3   3   1]
>>>
```

Comment: Of course... almost answered myself in the question! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: can smn explain [group for _, group in grouped] how it works?

Comment: @bcikili, it is equivalent to [group for name, group in grouped]. The underscore is used to emphasize that we don't care about the name.